# Inheritence in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am practicing in Node and can't undestand how to inherit from object. 
I want to call specified controller from my router. Controller is inherited from base controller. But when I try to call base controller methods I always get undefined. How to inherit and call parents method correctly?

I am a newbie, so may be I don't get basics right.

My code:

router.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var MainController = require('app/controller/mainController');

    var controller = new MainController(req, res);

    // Here I get undefined;
    console.log(controller.getWidgets);

    controller.index();

  });
}
```

mainController.js:

```
var util = require('util');
var BaseController = require('./BaseController');

util.inherits(MainController, BaseController);

function MainController(req,res) {

  this.index = function() {

    // Here I want to use method from parent (BaseController)
    // to get page widgets, also get undefined.
    var widgets = this.getWidgets();

    // console log also says there is no such method
    console.log(this.getWidgets);        

    // then render page
    res.render(...)
  }

}

module.exports = MainController;
```

BaseController.js:

```
function BaseController() {

  // example code
  this.getWidgets = function() {
    console.log('widgets are sent');
    return 123;
  }

}

module.exports = BaseController;
```

Comment: getWidgets is an own method, not an inherited one...

Comment: You forgot the super call to your parent constructor: put `BaseController.call(this)` in the first line of your `MainController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getWidgets should be defined as a prototype method.

```
function BaseController() {

}

BaseController.prototype.getWidgets = function() {
  console.log('widgets are sent');
  return 123;
}

module.exports = BaseController;
```

Comment: I thought that `BaseController.prototype.getWidgets` and `this.getWidgets` are the same thing. What is the difference? Where I can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript in general, you are not in a traditional OOP environement.

The inheritence is "prototypical".

Meaning "inherited" object are object sharing the same prototype as the "parent" you should read that article [prototypical inheritence](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance)

On a sidenote, I made a small gist on concrete example on some prototype behavior that can feel strange at first [gist](https://gist.github.com/bcharp/712d6d9bfaf55b3c5d81)